# Find matrix of linear transformation in a different basis and write it in terms of the original matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Problem asks how does matrix $A$ of some linear transformation in basis $B=\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ look like in basis $B'=\{v_1+v_2,v_2+v_3,v_3\}$ so I found transition matrices that are lower triangular and the first one from $B' \to B$ is:
$$T=
\begin{bmatrix}
    1  & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 1& 0 \\
   0 &1 &1
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
and its inverse ie. $B\to B'$ :
$$T^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
    1  & 0 & 0 \\
    -1 & 1& 0 \\
   1 &-1 &1
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
So the problem says only about $A$ like they want the result in $A$. However I could not solving without writing down its entries: So I say $$A=\sum_{i=0,j=0}^{i=3,j=3}a_{ij}$$. And I multiplied it out and I got something really ugly so :
$$T^{-1}AT=
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11}+a_{12}  & a_{12}+a_{13} & a_{13} \\
    a_{21}+a_{22}-(a_{11}+a_{12})& a_{22}+a_{23}-(a_{12}+a_{13})& a_{23}-a_{13} \\
   a_{11}+a_{12}+a_{31}+a_{32}-(a_{22}+a_{21}) &a_{12}+a_{13}+a_{32}+a_{33}-(a_{22}+a_{23}) &a_{13}+a_{33}-a_{23}
\end{bmatrix} $$
I cannot really see how could  I write it in terms of $A$ so I assume there must be some mistake, but as I am saying the exercise does not explicitly say "write it in terms of $A$", but I would expect it from how it is phrased.

Answer (score 1):

It is known that the new components of a vector $v$ under a change of base is $T^{-1}v$, then we have 
$$Av=ATT^{-1}v,$$ 
and 
$$T^{-1}(Av)=(T^{-1}AT)(T^{-1}v)$$ 
where we can see how the new components  $T^{-1}(Av)$ are related by $T^{-1}AT$ with the new components $T^{-1}v$

Answer (score 0):

It should be $TAT^{-1}$, so that first you get back to the standard basis, apply $A$, and then go back to the basis you want.

In the end, you want a map $B^{\prime} \to B^{\prime}$. $T:B  \to B^{\prime}$ is the matrix you describe, so doing $T$ firsts does not make sense

Comment: I don't agree the order is right $T^{-1}$ times A gives me A from $B' \to B$ and then multiplying from the right with $T$ I get what I should get. Multipling in reverse order vould give me a transpose of this result. Whats more I dont know the coordinates of $v_i$'s in standard basis so how should I find transition matrix to the standard basis? and why ?

Comment: just notice that coordinates of first vector from $B'$ in $B$ is $(1,1,0)$ not the other way around. Same with the rest of vectors

Comment: The "domains" do not match up, since $T$ is written in terms of the standard basis

Comment: But T is not writen in terms of the standard basis T is an identity transformation form V (in B') to V (in B).